# How to properly design an Adapter pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, adapter

I have an Application where I want to Implement an Adapter pattern. 
I have  different **types of sources** for which there are different Adapter and there can be multiple **sources of single type**. 
The question is do I instantiate a single Adapter for each type or individual sources?
Also why?

Answer (score 2):

For each source, you would want to create an instance. If several sources are of the same kind, you would probably create several instances of the same Type.

Comment: Why is that?If i have a Adapter for each type, i can ask the Adapter to get all the sources that around. If its other way around, Would I not have to delegate that responsibility to something else?